# How to implement a place value based multiplication algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, integer

### Place value (positional) encoded numbers

To make it possible to multiply a number in a place value based fashion, I have encoded numbers in a list format, digit by digit in reverse order. Say for example 34 is `[4 3]` and 12 is `[2 1]`.

To encode numbers I use:

```
def eN(n):
    return list(map(int, reversed(str(n))))
```

To decode I use:

```
def dN(l):
    return int(''.join(map(str, reversed(l))))
```

So that: `dN(eN(34)) -> 34`

Positive integers can be from 0 to any digits long.

### Multiplication constraints

Now, I need to create a multiplication algorithm with the next constraints:

1.

Division method to find out integer and remainder part of the divided number that satisfy this function:

```
from math import floor
# div(5, 3) -> [1, 2]
def div(n, base = 10):
    return [floor(n / base), n % base]
```

2. only permitted arithmetic operations are `div`, `*` and `+` methods, which however can be used in conjunction with recursion
3. numbers must be encoded as stated above except the base is given as a native integer from 2 and up
4. at any part of the algorithm numbers cannot exceed two digits. For example 9+9 = 18 or 9*9=81 are good, but 100 is too much
5. result should also be a list of numbers encoded in a reverse list format. numbers in a list must be in single digits so that we can use decode function (`dN`) to transform it back to native integer
6. algorithm should work with any number base by using `div` or builtin Python  [divmod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) as suggested by @ShadowRanger.

Maybe other restrictions becomes necessary to stress, when answers are suggested.

### Alleged algorithm

I would think of a root function similar to this, where two encoded numbers are given as arguments, plus an optional base number, default is 10:

```
def mul(a, b, base = 10):
    def _(c, d, e):
        # arithmetics, carrying digits, list processing, recursive calls goes here
        pass
    # initially, the first digit of the number a is reduced and 10^0 parts of the both numbers are multiplied and "div"ided
    return _(a[1:], b, div(a[0]*b[0], base))
```

Finally, the expected result is:

```
mul(eN(34), eN(12)) # [8, 0, 4]
```

or

```
dN([8, 0, 4]) # 408
```

If necessary, I can add more to the multiplication `_` function, which only has pass at the moment...

---

Added later...

### Working, but messy and unoptimized version of the algo

One might want to use this as a starting point for optimization. I should note, that this should already do the job exactly as I need, but other approaches are welcome:

```
def mul(a, b, base = 10):
    # init function with some default values
    def _(c, d, f = [], g = [], h = [], e = 0):
        # if there are no more items in list d, this is the end result
        if not d:
            return h + f
        # if there are items in list list c, get integer and reminder parts and other stuff 
        # and proceed with the rest of the list c
        if c:
            x = divmod(c[0] * d[0] + (f.pop(1) if len(f) > 1 else 0) + e, base)
            return _(c[1:], d, f, g + [x[1]], h, x[0])
        # else we have reached the end of the list c and must begin again with the rest of the list d!
        # also append reminders to the result lists h and f, not that content of f comes from g at this point
        return _(a, d[1:], (g + [e] if e else g), [], (h + [f[0]] if f else h))
    # start calling the recursive function and return the end result
    return _(a, b)
```

I will accept any answer that does the same job, even the ones using above code, if solution makes good improvements like minifies the need of lists i.e. usage of memory, or other way simplifies and explains the solution.

Comment: I think that your question is very ill-phrased. It is not clear straight from the start, what exactly is the goal here. You start with a description of encoding/decoding, and then use say "Now, I need to proceed multiplication algorithm" - what does that have to do with encoding/decoding??? Maybe the readers can find out further down the question, but personally, I would try to make it easier on them, and reorder things, so that the context becomes more vivid.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find easier ways to explain it.

Comment: Side-note: Aside from the default value for `base`, your `div` function is a slow version of the built-in `divmod`. You should also know that `//` is the floor division operator; `floor(n / base)` is correctly (in that it works for any sized value, not just values small enough to represent accurately as a `C` `double`) done with `floor // base`.

Comment: Also, why do you expect the `_` function to return anything useful? It's an empty function.

Comment: I will take a look to the div optimization tips, thanks. _ is for the main algo that Im looking after so the implementation could go there... I have read about Montecarlo and Chinese multiplication method but yet been unable to apply them to this task. Addition and substraction I have managed to implement in place value modulo method. Key point is trying to do the task with as small number digits and list sizes as possible. So one kight take this as an optimization task also.